# How can I change the state of one React component based on the value of its sibling?

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to build a form in React that has some auto-filling features. I'm trying to create the ability to 'lock' the value of LossOver50k to either 'Yes' or 'No' based on the ReplacementCost value to prevent input errors. The code I have right now is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReplacementCost from "./ReplacementCost";
import LossOver50K from "./LossOver50K";

const LossAmount = () => {
  const [replacementCost, setReplacementCost] = useState("");
  const [highValue, setHighValue] = useState("No");

  const handleChange = (newReplacementCost) => {
    setReplacementCost(newReplacementCost);
    if (replacementCost >= 50000) {
      setHighValue("Yes");
    }
  };

  // const changeHighValue = (newHighValue) => {
  //   setHighValue(newHighValue);
  // };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReplacementCost value={replacementCost} onChange={handleChange} />
      <LossOver50K value={highValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LossAmount;
```

My commented piece was working as an onChange handler on the LossOver50k component but I'm trying to manipulate the value of LossOver50k if the value of Replacement Cost is equal to or greater than 50,000. I have each of these components successfully updating their state when I input the values directly by passing the props down to the child components. Any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: You don't actually tell whats not working, I guess the problem with the condition `replacementCost >= 50000`, please create **reproducible example** when asking a question. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition should be with the most updated value and not with a staled one (as `setState` is async):

```
const handleChange = (newReplacementCost) => {
    setReplacementCost(newReplacementCost);
    if (newReplacementCost >= 50000) {
      setHighValue("Yes");
    }
  };
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for that info. Seems obvious now but was just not clicking for me.